# How to hide both line and circle in Python Bokeh plot using legend click policy?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have a Python Bokeh plot (multiple plot lines+circle) as follows:

```
 output_notebook()

source = ColumnDataSource(da)

col_names = paises

p = figure(
 title = "A",
 x_axis_type="datetime",
 plot_width=800,
 plot_height=400,
 sizing_mode='scale_width',
 toolbar_location='above',
 tools ="box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom" )

p_dict = dict()


for col, c, col_name in zip(da.columns, color, col_names):
 p_dict[col_name] = p.circle('date', col, source=source, color=c, size=3.5, line_width=0.5, fill_color=None)
 p_dict[col_name] = p.line('date', col, source=source, color=c, line_width=1) 

 p.add_tools(HoverTool( 
     toggleable=False,
     renderers=[p_dict[col_name]],
     tooltips=[('datetime','@date{%F}'),(col, f'@{col}')],
     formatters={'@date': 'datetime'}
 ))


legend = Legend(items=[(x, [p_dict[x]]) for x in p_dict])


p.add_layout(legend)

p.legend.click_policy="hide"

p.legend.label_text_font_size = "1vw"
p.legend.location = 'top_left'
p.left[0].formatter.use_scientific = False

show(p)
```

I am using `legend.click_policy="hide"` to hide the lines but when clicking the legend, only hides the circle but not the line. Is there a way to hide both line and circle?

Thanks!

Comment: Could be bug or missing featue. Please provid a *complete* reproducer script, that can actually be run as-is.

Comment: I don't think that is a bug. It seems that the policy only applies to the last geometry it finds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had to post the complete code (I already changed it so that the question is well understood). I found the solution adding the legend to the for loop:

```
output_notebook()

source = ColumnDataSource(da)

col_names = paises

p = figure(
    title = "A",
    x_axis_type="datetime",
    plot_width=800,
    plot_height=400,
    sizing_mode='scale_width',
    toolbar_location='above',
    tools ="box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom" )

p_dict = dict()


for col, c, col_name, leg in zip(da.columns, color, col_names, paises):
    p_dict[col_name] = p.circle('date', col, source=source, color=c, size=3.5, line_width=0.5, fill_color=None, legend_label = leg)
    p_dict[col_name] = p.line('date', col, source=source, color=c, line_width=1, legend_label = leg) 

    p.add_tools(HoverTool( 
        toggleable=False,
        renderers=[p_dict[col_name]],
        tooltips=[('datetime','@date{%F}'),(col, f'@{col}')],
        formatters={'@date': 'datetime'}
    ))


p.legend.click_policy="hide"

p.legend.label_text_font_size = "1vw"
p.legend.location = 'top_left'
p.left[0].formatter.use_scientific = False

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid constructing the legend manually, you can just provide the glyph functions with the same `legend_name`:

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[0, 2, 1]))

p = figure()

p.line('x', 'y', source=source, legend_label='line_with_circles')
p.circle('x', 'y', source=source, legend_label='line_with_circles')

p.legend.click_policy = "hide"
p.legend.location = 'top_left'

show(p)
```

If you have to create the legend manually, just create a single legend item and provide it with both renderers.

Comment: Hello @Eugene Pakhomov, I can't create legends manually because there are tenths of line plots

Comment: Well, then just use the approach from my code example. Or does it somehow not work for you as well?